# How to make Docker for macOS listen on something other than port 8000?

Tags: macos, port, docker

I need to run other programs on my machine that also use port 8000 by default, so I need to change one of them.  For example, I would like Docker to run on port 8065.

I don't see anything in the docker json conf to do this.  I see some `-H` options but I am not sure what the exact command would be.  Nothing in the gui dropdown deskbar config menu offers any way to do this afaik.

I tried `export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:8065` and then `open -a Docker` but that resulted in a failure to successfully start Docker.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've *already* had Docker running *successfully* in the past; you might want to try

```
sudo /usr/bin/docker daemon -H tcp://127.0.0.1:8065
```

But you **must** ensure that Docker is not *already* running. Also note the addition of `sudo` in the command above. This may well be why your noted attempt failed. You may also require adding an additional `-H` for the `socket` Docker listens on.

I notice an **Advanced** section under the **Daemon** section of the `UI` in the [OSX Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/). Does it offer the option to choose which `port` Docker runs on?

In any case the documentation I linked above. Provides access to the configurastion files, and sections you require to make your desired adjustment.

Comment: Unfortunately, in Docker Desktop "Daemon" tab text-entry area for `daemon.json`, I get:

```
"hosts":
  Cannot be used in Docker Desktop
```

As for `$ sudo /usr/local/bin/docker daemon -H tcp://127.0.0.1:8065`, I get:

docker: 'daemon' is not a docker command.

Comment: Also, note that the correct key for `-H` in the `daemon.json` is `hosts`, not `host` as listed in the canonical doc: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file

I can tell because the Docker Desktop app complains if I use `host`, but `hosts` is not flagged as invalid (although as noted above, it is indeed flagged as not supported in Docker Desktop).